# Tailwind CSS html section not taking padding bottom

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm having issues with using tailwinds "pb" class to add bottom space/padding to the html section area. I have forced a style to overwrite the spacing by adding a style tag with a padding bottom of 100px in the element. How can I use tailwind pb or mb to create the bottom space in the section tag instead of adding a style tag.

HTML(TailwindCSS)

```
**<section class="bg-formBgBlack flex" style="padding-bottom:100px;">
    <div class="max-w-6xl px-5 mx-auto mt-10">
        <h2 class="text-2xl font-bold text-center text-white pb-8 md:text-4xl">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, onsectetur adipiscing elit
        </h2>
        <div class="flex container bg-white p-6 mx-auto rounded-lg max-h-full">
            <div class="px-0 pt-8 pb-8 md:pt-16 md:px-32">
                <span class="text-gray-700 uppercase flex text-left text-xs md:text-sm">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                    consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
                <span class="text-black font-bold flex text-left text-2xl md:text-2xl">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                    consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
                <span class="text-gray-700 flex pt-2 pb-2 text-left text-xs md:text-sm">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                    consectetur adipiscing elit.?&nbsp;<a href="#" class="no-underline text-signUpGreen">Lorem ipsum</a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no utility class by default for 100px so you can just use arbitrary values, https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-arbitrary-values

So the class to use in square bracket notation is `pb-[100px]`.

If you will use that spacing in your project many times, you can also customize the spacing by configuring `tailwind.conf.js` as described here, https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-spacing

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      spacing: {
        '25': '6.25rem',
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad that worked for you. I just updated the config option from `'100'` to `'25'` which fits in better with Tailwind's "one spacing unit is equal to 0.25rem" spacing scale. `pb-24` equals 96px, and with the addition to the config, `p-25` will equal 100px.